# VBA .FindNext while setting other object in loop failing

Tags: vba, excel, do-while

I'm attempting to execute a do-while loop with the .FindNext method to find multiple instances in a column. On its own, it works fine.
However. when trying to find a corresponding value in another sheet within the same loop, it throws the 'Object variable or With block variable not set' error (91).

```
If Not found_title Is Nothing Then

    first_cell_address = found_title.Address

    Do
        Set found_url = url_lookup.Find(found_title.Offset(0, -4).Value)
        Debug.Print ("looped")
        Set found_title = title_lookup.FindNext(found_title)

    Loop While first_cell_address <> found_title.Address

End If
```

When I comment out 'set found_url...' it works fine, but when including it, the 'found_title' object has been set to nothing by the time it reaches the while condition for the first time. As the FindNext method wraps around the range, I can't see why this is being set to nothing when there must be at least one of them to enter the if statement in the first place.

SOLUTION:

As per rory's response, the change was:

```
Set found_title = title_lookup.Find(title, After:=Range(found_title.Address))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you nest one `Find` within another, you can't use `FindNext` on the outer one. You have to repeat the original `Find` and specify the `After` argument as the previous found cell.

Comment: Thank you, that sorted the problem. i never considered that the 'find' methods themselves were nested.